# Knapsack of mixture with constraints

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find the optimized mixture for a specific set of substances. Each of those substances have characteristics that I want to optimize in the mixture (some characteristics I want to minimize and others I want to maximize). But I can't have more than 50% (random value that will be set on running time) of one of those substances in the mixture.

I thought about using Genetic Algorithm, but I'm not sure it's the best approach for this problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Edit: it doesn't need to be a evolutionary algorithm.

Comment: Any reason not to use LP or MIP? How big is the problem?

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick The only reason not to use LP was that I didn't knew about it before you mentioned. So thanks. I'll try that approach.
MIP as I understood works only for integers, but I need for real values. Is that correct?

Comment: As Issouf says, MIP is most often used with a mixture of real and integer values. The underlying technology is usually something like the simplex algorithm to solve the 'relaxed' problem (ignoring the requirement for some values to be integers) which only works for continuous-valued real variables. Then an additional 'layer' of stuff is added to do something like branch and bound, repeatedly setting some values to be integers and re-solving the (smaller) relaxed problem.

Answer (score 0):

MIP mean that mixe integer programming : it works with reals and integers variable.